# Separate an Object into Properties for manipulation before db.SaveChanges();

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a comments object that I can save changes with when a form is submitted through the following code, inside the controller.

```
db.Comments.AddObject(comment);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The comment object may have one too many properties? E.g.. firstname, lastname, email and address. How can I pull the individual properties? Out of the object so I can manipulate them before I save changes, inside the controller?

Comment: Do you use model binding? Please show us your action code (the relevant method inside the controller, that accepts the user input for saving).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
string FirstName = comment.FirstName;
FirstName = "A" + FirstName;
comment.FirstName = FirstName;

db.Comments.AddObject(comment);
db.SaveChanges();
```